# How to disable paging in asp.net MVC jqGrid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, jqgrid

From controller i mention this code for returning value.
`return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list.AsQueryable().ToGridData(model), new Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.IsoDateTimeConverter());`

jqGrid code: Here i binding list of records in MVC grid control. Below code i used in chtml view page.

```
@{    
            GridPagerControl gpc = new GridPagerControl();
            gpc.ShowAdd(false).ShowDel(false).ShowSearch(false, false).ShowEdit(false);
        }

@Html.Grid(
                            new GridControl()
                                .SetName("grdHead")
                                .SetShowFilterToolbar(true)
                                .SetIsAutoSize(true)
                                .SetListUrl(Url.Action("WorkflowHeadList", "WorkFlow"))
                                .SetHeight("500")
                                .SetWidth("300")
                                .SetPager(gpc)
                                .SetPageSize(1000)//I don't want to apply page size
                                .SetAdditionalAttributes("sortorder:'desc')
                                                                    .SetColumns<Alfaraa.LaborActivityMonitor.Model.GetWorkflowList_Result>(
                                                column =>
                                                {
                                                    column.Add(x => x.ActivityHeadId).SetAsPrimaryKey().SetHidden(true);
                                                    column.Add(x => x.WFInstanceName).SetCaption("Workflow");
                                                    column.Add(x => x.ActivityDate).SetCaption("Allocation Date");
                                                    column.Add(x => x.CreatedDateTime).SetIsDefaultSort();
                                                    column.Add(x => x.CreatedBy).SetCaption("Submitted By");
                                                    column.Add(x => x.Status).SetCaption("Status");
                                                    column.Add(x => x.StateDesc).SetCaption("Assigned To");
                                                    column.Add(x => x.AssignedDate).SetCaption("Assigned Date"); 
                                                }
                                        )
                        )
```

In above grid i need to disable paging functionality.

If i comment `.SetPageSize(1000)` function, its give me below error.

```
protected void Initialize(IQueryable<T> source, int index, int pageSize, int? totalCount)
        {
            //### argument checking
            if (index < 0)
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("PageIndex cannot be below 0.");
            }
            if (pageSize < 1)
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("PageSize cannot be less than 1.");//this error will throw
            }
.....
}
```

Error message:

```
Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: PageSize cannot be less than 1.
```

Comment: Where `Initialize` method used? AFAIK if `SetPageSize` value not set, then `pageSize` argument in `Initialize` will set to 0 (default value of `int`) and triggered second `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`.

Comment: that method defined under MVC control library class "PagedList". By default PageSize value is 0.